# jupyter kernet stop automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to donwload data my personnal website.

My problem is, at some point when I am downloading data by saving it in a Json file.jupyter kenerl stopped and I had a a pop :

Kernel restarting:
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

```
and on invite command with the commad : python scrap.py
At some point I had this error :RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Who can I do to continue to download, please ?

Here is my code :

```
leafdata = {}
leafdata["data"]=[]
listJon=[]

for autor in Listo:


       site= "http://extracts.blabla.mydata="+str(names)

        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
        page = urlopen(req)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        DataBodyExtract= soup.find('body')

        JsonDataExtract= re.findall( r'{"Extracts":.*"PageCount":[0-9]+}',str(DataBodyExtract ) )

        with open('./mydata/dataLeafWk.json','a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(JsonDataExtract[0]+str(','))  


        #leafdata["data"].append(JsonDataExtract[0])

        time.sleep( random.randint(15,30) )
```